# Laravel validation required|exists with exception of 0

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

HTML form has select dropdown with list of existing categories and no category with id=0.
CategoryStoreRequest must check if the category_id from the form belongs to existing category or is 0

Something like that

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        "name" => "required|min:3",
        "category_id" => "required|exists:categories,id,except_if_value_is_0"
    ];
}
```

What is the most elegant way to achieve it?

Comment: Your question is bit confusing? please explain little bit more

Answer (score 14):

It turns out that `nullable` is one quite elegant way to do it. When submitting the form then category_id array key is still present but its value is null. nullable allows the key to be null also.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        "name" => "required|min:3",
        "category_id" => "nullable|exists:categories,id"
    ];
}
```

In addition the select value must be ""

```
<select name="category_id">
    <option value="">No category selection</option>
    <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, then the empty value will pass the `nullable` rule, but not the `exists` rule IIRC.

Comment: This is the point. If value is given then it must pass the exists rule. Otherwise there is only one exception allowed.

Answer (score 4):

you can create new validation to handle
see this example:
in your_project_name/app/providers/AppServicesProviders.php

```
Validator::extend(
        'exists_or_null',
        function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            if($value == 0 || is_null($value)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $validator = Validator::make([$attribute => $value], [
                    $attribute => 'exists:' . implode(",", $parameters)
                ]);
                return !$validator->fails();
            }
        }
    );
```

in your example do that

```
public function rules() {
return [
    "name" => "required|min:3",
    "category_id" => "required|exists_or_null:categories,id"
];
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sometimes`. In this case, the rule will only be applied if a filled category_id is submitted.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        "name" => "required|min:3",
        "category_id" => "sometimes|exists:categories,id"
    ];
}
```

Change your html, so that there's **no value** set:

```
<select name="category_id">
    <option value="">No category selection</option>
    <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for `exists or 0`, you could set your custom zero value to `NULL` or an empty string.

You need to change a little bit of your logic, but then you can validate it correctly by using the [sometimes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) rule:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        "name" => "required|min:3",
        "category_id" => "sometimes|exists:categories,id"
    ];
}
```